# How to send multipart/form data to web server from android?

Tags: java, android, html, forms, http

I have a trouble with posting the form data to web server. Everytime i try to post i get this response from server "No message received" so obviously there is something wrong with the code. Am i missing something?

Here is the HTML part that i am trying to post:

```
<form id="post" action="url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<input id="board" name="board" value="hiekkalaatikko" type="hidden">
<input id="thread" name="thread" value="0" type="hidden">

<input name="uuid" id="uuid" value="1e54a561-b08e-4bad-b9b6-e618ccd91ef5" type="hidden">
<input name="email" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;" type="text">
<table id="postform">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="postername">Viestinimi</label></td>
<td><input name="postername" id="postername" onkeyup="checkName('poster');" type="text"> <span id="posternamestatus"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="functions">Toiminnot</label></td>
<td><input name="functions" id="functions" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="subject">Aihe</label></td>
<td>
<input name="subject" id="subject" maxlength="60" type="text">
<input value="Lähetä" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">
<span id="qrinfo"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="msg">Viesti</label></td>
<td><textarea name="msg" id="msg" rows="4" cols="48"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="file">Tiedosto</label></td>
<td><input name="file" id="file" size="35" type="file"> <label for="spoilerfile">Juonipaljastus</label> <input id="spoilerfile" name="spoilerfile" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="embed">Upote</label></td>
<td>
<input name="embed" id="embed" type="text">
<select name="embedtype" id="embedtype">
<option value="9">Naamapalmu</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">YouTube</option>
<option value="7">LiveLeak</option>
<option value="4">SoundCloud</option>
<option value="8">Vimeo</option>
<option value="5">Vocaroo</option>
</select> <a href="http://ylilauta.org/scripts/help.php?embeds" onclick="window.open(this.href,'embedhelp','width=640,height=480,scrollbars=yes'); return false;">Upotusohje</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<ul id="postinfo">
<li>Sallitut tiedostotyypit ovat gif, jpeg, jpg, mp3, png, rar, swf, zip</li>
<li>Suurin sallittu tiedostokoko on 10 Mt.</li>
<li>2642 käyttäjää paikalla. (<a href="http://ylilauta.org/online.php">Graafi</a>)</li>
<li>Yhteensä 10161 viestiä on lähetetty tälle alueelle. (<a href="http://ylilauta.org/postcount.php">Graafi</a>)</li>
<li><a href="http://ylilauta.org/hiekkalaatikko/threadlist">Aiheluettelo</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is android side code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.send:
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        try{
            reqEntity.addPart("content-type", new StringBody("text/html; charset=UTF-8"));
            reqEntity.addPart("board", new StringBody("hiekkalaatikko",Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("thread", new StringBody("0", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("anticaptcha", new StringBody(anticaptcha, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("uuid", new StringBody(UUID, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody("", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("postername", new StringBody(mNameField.getText().toString(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("functions", new StringBody(mActionField.getText().toString(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("subject", new StringBody(mSubjectField.getText().toString(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("submit", new StringBody("Lähetä", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("subboard", new StringBody("0", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("msg", new StringBody(mMessageField.getText().toString(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("spoilerfile", new StringBody("checked", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            reqEntity.addPart("embed", new StringBody("9", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        postReply reply = new postReply();
        reply.execute(reqEntity);
        break;
    }
}

public class postReply extends AsyncTask<MultipartEntity, Void, HttpResponse>{

    @Override
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(MultipartEntity... arg0) {
        array = arg0[0];
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url");
            httppost.setEntity(arg0[0]);
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
            System.out.println(s);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("Post", "Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Edit: I tryed to send this data to test server from browser and this application. I don't see any data missing, but i get still this same response "No message received" from the target server.

This is send from the browser:

```
    Time: Wed, 10 Apr 13 11:33:30 -0700
Source ip: ***********

Headers (Some may be inserted by server)
UNIQUE_ID = UWWwetBx6hIAAA7wUFQAAAAK
HTTP_HOST = posttestserver.com
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
HTTP_ACCEPT = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = fi-fi,fi;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = gzip, deflate
HTTP_CONNECTION = close
CONTENT_TYPE = multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1974624714324
CONTENT_LENGTH = 1326
REMOTE_ADDR = **************
REMOTE_PORT = 11440
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD = POST
QUERY_STRING = dir=example
REQUEST_URI = /post.php?dir=example
REQUEST_TIME = 1365618810

Post Params:
key: 'board' value: 'hiekkalaatikko'
key: 'thread' value: '0'
key: 'uuid' value: '1e54a561-b08e-4bad-b9b6-e618ccd91ef5'
key: 'email' value: ''
key: 'postername' value: 'name '
key: 'functions' value: 'functions'
key: 'subject' value: ''
key: 'submit' value: 'Lähetä'
key: 'msg' value: 'Test message'
key: 'embed' value: ''
key: 'embedtype' value: '1'
Empty post body.

== Multipart File upload. ==
Received 1 file(s)
 0: posted name=file
    name: 
    type: 
    error: 4
    size: 0
File specified was not uploaded. Possible file upload attack.
```

And this is from my application:

```
    Time: Wed, 10 Apr 13 11:35:01 -0700
Source *************

Headers (Some may be inserted by server)
UNIQUE_ID = UWWw1dBx6hIAAA7bTL8AAAAD
HTTP_HTTP_ACCEPT = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = fi-fi,fi;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
CONTENT_LENGTH = 2189
CONTENT_TYPE = multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------321842129511553
HTTP_HOST = posttestserver.com
HTTP_CONNECTION = close
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
REMOTE_ADDR = ***************
REMOTE_PORT = 11448
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD = POST
QUERY_STRING = dir=example
REQUEST_URI = /post.php?dir=example
REQUEST_TIME = 1365618901

Post Params:
key: 'board' value: 'hiekkalaatikko'
key: 'thread' value: '0'
key: 'uuid' value: '0c44a067-802d-480d-b636-335d6d837c13'
key: 'email' value: ''
key: 'subject' value: ''
key: 'embed' value: ''
key: 'embedtype' value: '9'
key: 'msg' value: 'Test message'
key: 'submit' value: 'Luo aihe'
key: 'postername' value: 'Name'
key: 'functions' value: 'Functions'
key: 'noko' value: 'off'
Empty post body.

== Multipart File upload. ==
Received 0 file(s)
```

Comment: are you sure, than arg0[0] in line  httppost.setEntity(arg0[0]) it's quite the thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must try to encode your value by changing your MultipartEntry with. It can also help you repeating `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` everywhere

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, null, Charset.forName(HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Dont forget also to add this

```
 httpclient.getParams()
                .setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
```

add this line  before execute to see your request line that you are sending to the server

```
System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
```

and this also for to see response line from server

```
response.getStatusLine().toString()
```

add also this line to close the connection after httpresponse

```
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Comment: No change, I/System.out(18795): executing request POST http://ylilauta.org/post HTTP/1.1 response: I/System.out(18795): 200  Thanks anyway

Comment: @user1888162 do you still get this error? "No message received"
please post the full logcat outpu

Comment: @user1888162 add also this line to close the connection after httpresponse:  httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

Answer (score 4):

You're sending a barrage of entities rather than the `UrlEncoded` entity the server expects. Try following this pattern:

```
    List<NameValuePair> values = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
    values.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "board", "hiekkalaatikko" ) );
    values.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "thread", "0" ) );
    ...
    httppost.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity( values ) );
```

You won't really need multi-part entities unless you're sending files to the server.

Comment: I am also uploading files so multi-part entities is necessary

Answer (score 1):

**Use this method ::**

```
  public static String uploadFile2Server(String uploadUrl, String filePath,
        String serverKeyName) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "rn";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
    try {
        // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                filePath));
        // open a URL connection to the Server
        URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Allow Inputs
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""
                + serverKeyName + "\";filename=\"" + filePath + " \""
                + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        // create a buffer of maximum size
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        // close streams
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
        inputStream = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please add some description to what exactly your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set a boundary in the constructor of your MultipartEntity object in case you are defining one server side.

```
// MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode mode, String boundary, Charset charset) 
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(null, "your boundary", null);
```

*Extra info about boundaries: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

Comment: No change but thanks anyway. I added post results to my question